# Link text built in Jquery does not display clickable link on Razor Page

Tags: html, jquery, hyperlink, razor-pages

This Jquery code on a Razor Page creates an "a" tag string that looks ok, but, when displayed on the Razor Page, it is just a string of text, not a clickable link.

Any ideas? I have searched but nothing seems to apply for something this simple. Maybe I am dense.

```
var xxx =encodeURIComponent($('#Dances_Moderated_AddressMap').val() + " " + $('#Dances_Moderated_CityMap').val() + " " + $('#Dances_Moderated_StateMap').val());


var wholeEnchilada =  "<a href=\"https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + xxx + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + $('#Dances_Moderated_EventName').val() + "</a>";

$('#URL').text(wholeEnchilada);
```

=======================

Here is the Html area with the id="URL". I am trying to make the "No Map" changed to a link on google maps page. The google maps syntax works in other processes I have built. The "No Map" gets changed, but it is not a clickable link.

```
<tr>
    <td id="URL">
        No Map
    </td>
</tr>
```

============================
The

```
$('#URL').text(wholeEnchilada);
```

displays the string below on the Razor Page

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/800%20NE%20Oregon%20St%20Portland%20OR" target="_blank">Really Big Dance</a>
```

What I was hoping for was a blue colored link

If I copy out the href attribute and past it in the browser it works.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/800%20NE%20Oregon%20St%20Portland%20OR
```

Comment: Hi can you try with `.html()` instead of `.text()` .Here is [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/srwo76xq/)

Comment: @Swati I love you!! please make this an answer and I will accept it! Worked like a charm so simple. I didn't see your comment because Stack doesn't email comments only answers. Thanks!